# Vue.js bind ajax loaded v-on click handlers

Tags: ajax, vue.js

I'm taking over a project that has a lot of AJAX loaded HTML snippets.  I want to progressively introduce Vue.js where I can.  I'm not trying to async load any component definitions or javascript, but I would like to load an HTML snippet that has a `v-on:click` binding like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="showModal=true">
    Show Modal Dialog
</button>
```

Is there anyway for vuejs to parse html snippets that come down from jQuery and read the v-* attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`<v-runtime-template>`](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template) to load Vue template strings at runtime:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <template v-if="template">
      <v-runtime-template :template="template"></v-runtime-template>
    </template>
    <div v-else>Loading...</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      template: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.template = this.getVueTemplateFromServer();
  },
  methods: {
    getVueTemplateFromServer() { /*...*/ }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n4xzjrp7lm)

Comment: It took me a a while to understand this approach.  But I think I can set the template after jQuery('.selector').load( uri ).  Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it was confusing for the demo to use `setTimeout` (to simulate the network request). I've updated the demo to use an actual network request to download the template string. Let me know if that clarifies things for you.